# AlpineJS can not use magic method $watch

Tags: events, watch, alpine.js

Having the following AlpineJS code and trying to use the magic method $watch, the code will fail with `ReferenceError: $watch is not defined`

```
window.experts = {
  apiUrl: 'http://test.local:8991/api/',
  data: [],
  list: [],
  expertsForm: null,
  expertType: 'all',
  queryUrl: '',
  currentPage: 1,
  sortByName: 'asc',
  sortByZip: 'asc',
  q: '',
  fetchStatus: 'loading...',
  retrieveList: () => {
    const membersUrl = `${experts.apiUrl}members?include=user,association,affiliate`;
    $watch('specialistType', (value) => console.log(value) );

    experts.apiCalls(membersUrl)
  },
  setExpertType: (type) => {
    console.log(type)
  },
  apiCalls: (url) => {
    const response = fetch(url).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        experts.fetchStatus = 'error'
      }

      return res.json()
    }).then(result => {
      experts.list = result.data;
      experts.data = result;
      experts.fetchStatus = 'idle'
    });
  }
}
```

what goes wrong in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing it via `this`. So it should be `this.$watch(value, callback)`.

Answer (score 1):

From alpine js [doc](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#using-magic-properties),

> If you want to access magic methods or properties from a component object, you can do so using the this context:

```
Alpine.data('dropdown', () => ({
    open: false,
 
    init() {
        this.$watch('open', () => {...})
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use arrow function and add `this`

```
retrieveList(){
    const membersUrl = `${experts.apiUrl}members?include=user,association,affiliate`;
    this.$watch('specialistType', (value) => console.log(value) );

    experts.apiCalls(membersUrl)
  },
```